# Start row number with custom number in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to set one column named 'vorder' with skip some unique id according to row number.

Table "*tblUser*" like:

```
╔════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦════════╗
║     Id ║ Firstname ║ Lastname ║ Birthday ║ Salary ║
╠════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬════════╣
║      1 ║ kinjal    ║ a        ║        1 ║    122 ║
║      2 ║ a         ║ s        ║        4 ║    122 ║
║      5 ║ b         ║ ds       ║       12 ║    234 ║
╚════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩════════╝
```

Now, I want to update Birthday with skip where Id not 1 according to id descending order.

I want to result like

```
╔════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦════════╗
║     Id ║ Firstname ║ Lastname ║ Birthday ║ Salary ║
╠════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬════════╣
║      1 ║ kinjal    ║ a        ║        1 ║    122 ║
║      2 ║ a         ║ s        ║        3 ║    122 ║
║      5 ║ b         ║ ds       ║        2 ║    234 ║
╚════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩════════╝
```

but i have the following query

```
WITH CTE_USER(ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, BIRTHDAY, SALARY, ROW_NUM) 
 AS (SELECT *, 
            ROW_NUMBER() 
              OVER ( 
                ORDER BY ID DESC) AS row_num 
     FROM   TBLUSER 
     WHERE  ID <> 1) 
UPDATE TBLUSER 
SET    BIRTHDAY = CTE_USER.ROW_NUM 
FROM   TBLUSER 
       INNER JOIN CTE_USER 
               ON TBLUSER.ID = CTE_USER.ID
```

It's result is :

```
╔════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦════════╗
║     Id ║ Firstname ║ Lastname ║ Birthday ║ Salary ║
╠════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬════════╣
║      1 ║ kinjal    ║ a        ║        1 ║    122 ║
║      2 ║ a         ║ s        ║        3 ║    122 ║
║      5 ║ b         ║ ds       ║        1 ║    234 ║
╚════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩════════╝
```

Any Help?

Comment: `Birthday with skip where Id not 1 according to id descending order` its make confuse me explain clearly

Comment: That's why i have pasted table with actual result and expecting result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tblUser.ID DESC)+1 AS rowNbr,
        tblUser.*
    FROM
        tblUser
    WHERE NOT tblUser.Id=1
)
UPDATE CTE 
SET Birthday = rowNbr
```